# Convert Object properties to multiple object array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am sure this an elementary question, apologies for asking. I've had a good time searching on the this with no luck... I am looking for the following object transformation.

```
var test= { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}
```

Into this:

```
var test= [{ one: 1},{ two: 2},{ three: 3}]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Object.keys** and **Array map**

```js
var test = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}

var objArray = Object.keys(test).map(item => ({ [item]: test[item] }))

console.log(objArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` combined with `.map()`, here is a working snippet:

```js
var test= { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}

let newArr = Object.keys(test).map((el) => ({[el]: test[el]}));
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: It's now a 1:1 copy of the accepted answer, but at least it works

Answer (score 2):

with help of `entries` and `map`:

```js
var test= { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3};
var result = Object.entries(test).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v}));

console.log(result);
```